# running matlab code in .bat file on windows

Tags: windows, matlab, batch-file

Here's the code used in my .bat file

```
phreeqc first_trial_um_b.pqi
matlab -sd "C:\trialbatch" -r "clean_output.m"
matlab -sd "C:\trialbatch" -r "getCa.m"
pause
```

The phreeqc part works just fine, however the matlab code somehow doesn't run. When I type the matlab code manually into DOS, it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What type of file is phreeqc? If it is a Batch file: phreeqc.bat, then the lines following it will never be executed. To fix it, you must include a CALL command to execute phreeqc:

```
call phreeqc first_trial_um_b.pqi
matlab -sd "C:\trialbatch" -r "clean_output.m"
matlab -sd "C:\trialbatch" -r "getCa.m"
pause
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Phreeqc is a modelling program, and first_trial_um_b.pqi is the model input. This runs as expected in the .bat file. For some reason however, matlab is not "called" after this phreeqc step has been completed.

Comment: ok, managed to get it to work by adding call in front of matlab and somewhat changing the lingo after matlab. Thanks for the input, @Aacini!